# Failed to connect to MySQL: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, php, docker

I wrote [this](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker) docker-compose project. The [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) looks like this:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mgsv
      - MYSQL_USER=mgsv_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mgsvpass
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql123
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  www:
    build: ./mGSV 
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

The [index.php](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/blob/master/mGSV/index.php)  looks like this:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
//mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","mgsv_user","mgsvpass","mgsv");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else {
     echo "done";
  }
?>
```

And the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/blob/master/mGSV/Dockerfile) is based on a PHP container and looks like this.

```
FROM php:5-apache

RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
                openjdk-7-jdk \
                maven  \
        git \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-source extract \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysql mysqli pdo pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-source delete

RUN cd /var/www/html/ && git clone https://github.com/qunfengdong/mGSV.git

# Move the folder 'mgsv' to DocumentRoot of Apache web server. By default, the DocumentRoot of Apache is /var/www/ (speak to the system administrator to know the exact DocumentRoot).
RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV \
    && mkdir tmp \
    && chmod -R 777 tmp

RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV && sed -i.bak "s|'gsv'|'mgsv_user'|" lib/settings.php \ 
    && sed -i.bak "s|$database_pass = ''|$database_pass = 'mgsvpass'|" lib/settings.php \
    && sed -i.bak "s|cas-qshare.cas.unt.edu|localhost|" lib/settings.php

RUN cp /var/www/html/mGSV/Arial.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/

RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV/ws \
    && tar -xzf mgsv-ws-server.tar.gz

RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV/ws/mgsv-ws-server \ 
    && mvn package

RUN cp -f /var/www/html/mGSV/ws/mgsv-ws-server/target/ws-server-1.0RC1-jar-with-dependencies.jar /var/www/html/mGSV/ws/

RUN cd /var/www/html/mGSV/ws \ 
    && echo "mgsv_upload_url=http://localhost/mgsv" > config.properties \
    && echo "ws_publish_url=http\://localhost\:8081/MGSVService" >> config.properties \
    && java -jar ws-server-1.0RC1-jar-with-dependencies.jar &

COPY ./index.php /var/www/html/
RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

When using `http://localhost:8080/` this is the output which I got:

```
Hello World!
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 4
Failed to connect to MySQL: No such file or directory
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

I believe the issue here is that `localhost` is not your database host.  If that PHP script is running in the "www" docker container, `localhost` most likely does not have a listening MySQL server.  IIRC, the "file not found" error from mysqli is due to not finding the MySQL socket on `localhost`.  I also do not see that you are exposing any ports for the "db" image, so I am not sure how "www" is supposed to connect to a database running inside it.

You would want to find what the address to the "db" docker container is, and what port it is listening on, then reference that in your `mysqli_connect()` function.  An easier method, if you have a recent version of docker, would be to add your containers to the same Docker network and reference them by name.

EDIT: Docker Networking

You should read up on the networking feature [in the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/) as it is very useful.  You can probably use the following docker-compose.yml (not tested):

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mgsv
      - MYSQL_USER=mgsv_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mgsvpass
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql123
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - web-db-net

  www:
    build: ./mGSV 
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    networks:
      - web-db-net

networks:
    web-db-net:
```

Then change your connect line to refer to the db container by name (you would also need to specify port if not using the MySQL default, 3306):

```
$con = mysqli_connect("db","mgsv_user","mgsvpass","mgsv");
```

EDIT2:  fixed docker-compose.yml so that networks actually works

Comment: I'm running docker-ce 18.03. How would it be possible to add the containers to the same Docker network and reference them by name?

Comment: I made an edit to show some docker networking

Comment: Thank you but I got `ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', network must be a mapping, not a string.`. What did I miss?

Comment: as I mentioned, it was not tested.  I just tested it and noticed my mistake.  In the `networks` key, put a colon (`:`) at the end of the network name to make it a mapping.  i have edited the code in my answer to reflect what I just tested.

Comment: Thank you, but I got again `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 4
Failed to connect to MySQL: No such file or directory`. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure how I missed this, but I may have misread the error previously.  Have you installed the PHP extension that includes `mysqli_connect()`?  It almost seems that PHP cannot find that function

Comment: I did `RUN docker-php-source extract  && docker-php-ext-install mysql mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-source delete` Is there a `mysqli_connect`?

Comment: I think I was right the first time, there would have been a different error if the module was not installed.  I just ran your docker-compose.yml and dockerfile and the php script worked fine for me after replacing "localhost" with the hostname of the database container, "db" in the example.  You should make sure the docker network is getting setup correctly, easy test would be to try and ping the db container from your www container.  If you cannot ping then the docker network may not be setup correctly and would require more in depth docker troubleshooting to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

`localhost` has special meaning in mysqli (from [MySqli Quick Start Guide - Connections](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)):

> The hostname localhost has a special meaning. It is bound to the use of Unix domain sockets. It is not possible to open a TCP/IP connection using the hostname localhost you must use 127.0.0.1 instead.

I.e. if you use `localhost` mysqli will try to use unix sockets instead of using TCP networking. Since the mysql server is not running locally, the unix socket file does not exist. Now the error makes sense.

Comment: This is a very useful answer for my setup, in which I do _not_ use a docker-compose configuration. Thanks!